# What's the term for catching and rethrowing a java exception?

Tags: java, exception

I seem to remember a very specific term for situations like this:

```
try {
  operation();
} catch (SomeException se) {
  throw new OtherException(se);
}
```

-or-

```
try {
  operation();
} catch (SomeException se) {
  throw new OtherException("new message, forget original exception");
}
```

and I'd like to use that correct term in some documentation. Can someone please jog my memory?

---

**EDIT:** As I understand the link quoted by JB Nizet, chaining is the act of passing the original exception to the constructor of the new one so the stack trace will include the original one. But that's *not* the concept I'm looking for. Sorry if my question ended up being misleading this way.

Comment: @Kublai Khan: Not exactly what I was looking for, but +1 for a fun answer :)

Answer (score 4):

In response to your edit: In that case, you're just "throwing" an exception. It just so happens to be thrown in a catch block. Instead of using potentially confusing terminology such as "transforming" (which I think implies mutation, rather than something new), I suggest you just say what you are doing explicitly.

---

You are "wrapping" the caught exception with another. Another term for it is "exception chaining"

Note, that rethrowing an exception is different because you are not creating a new exception, just catching it to do some logging (or something) and then throwing it again. To demonstrate:

```
try {
  operation();
}
catch (SomeException se) {
  throw se;
}
```

Comment: I have added to your answer rather than creating a new one because my additional comment is basically an extension of what you were saying. I hope that is OK.

Comment: @mikej, I believe that's referred to as "propagating".

Comment: Exception chaining doesn't seem to capture what I was after; please see my answer to JB Nizet. I guess the "wrappings" have it, then. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It is called re-throwing or exception-translating to harmonize different api's to an abstracter one (often done in the spring framework).

Comment: "exception translating" sounds tantalizingly close to what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, that's the very term that Spring uses. See [`SQLExceptionTranslator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLExceptionTranslator.html) for example.

Answer (score 2):

I use "rethrow" without any shame.

Anyway what you are doing is **encapsulating** the exception inside a new one.

Answer (score 2):

**Exception wrapping** or **exception chaining**

Comment: Exception chaining doesn't seem to capture what I was after; please see my answer to JB Nizet. I guess the "wrappings" have it, then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exception translation is probably the term you're after then. http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=120

Comment: Also I believe exception chaining is possibly still the correct term: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/chained-exceptions.html

Comment: Thanks for the additional attention. I understood the Oracle article to be describing this embedding of the source exception information in the new exception (so you get a "caused by..." stack trace, etc). Translation or transformation seem to be the right buzzwords for the rest of what's happening, from the other responses.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've seen that referred to as wrapping an Exception. Sorry if that's not the term you're looking for.

Comment: Could be that wrapping is the right term. Somewhere I still think there's a "better" term, but so far most people say that's what it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is commonly called ["exception chaining"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html). I was introduced in [Java 1.4](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/chained-exceptions.html).

Comment: Thanks much for the helpful link! It helps me clarify what's going on. 

As I understand it, the "chaining" refers to making the original exception available as a cause for the new exception. But the concept I'm asking about would have the name I'm looking for even if I were *not* to pass in the original exception. It's more the "transforming" one exception type into another that I'm looking to characterize.

Answer (score 1):

It's also called as

> Exception Chaining

Comment: Correct answer to my original question but not what I was looking for (thanks, so have a +1 anyway!) See my edit for clarification.